# Минимальное вхождение строк между двумя строками определенные регулярным выражением при помощи sed

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sed

Голову ломаю уже часа 4, так и не смог добиться результата.

Суть такая. Нужно получить данные между двумя тегами из xml. Xml выглядит следующим образом:

```
<tag1>
    <property />
    <property />
    <property />
    <property />
</tag1>
<tag1>
    <property />
    <property />
    <property />
    <property />
</tag1>
```

Так вот, мне нужно получить данные между tag1 и /tag1 первого вхождения, а не от первого tag1 по последний /tag1.

Пользоваться xml нельзя, анализировать вынужден через потоковую обработку.

**UPD:**

ну вижу не понимание такого извращенного подхода =) я вас понимаю, ну попробуйте тогда и меня вы понять, опишу всю суть проблемы:

- Есть база данных. К ней формируется файл формата xml с ее описанием. Дабы этот файлик не потерялся при транспортировки по внутренней сети он прикрепляется к базе данных в виде альтернативного потока.
- После того как база данных и описание готова, она шифруется/криптуется и чтобы она весила меньше запаковывается в архив формата rar. Архив самораспаковывающийся.
- Чтобы понять, что в архиве расположено, без его распаковки, данные из альтернативного потока вносятся к комментарий к архиву. Получается комментарий в точности повторяет xml файл описания базы данных (да я знаю про ограничение комментария в 60кб)
- На стороне сервера под ОС линуховой, нужно собрать все описания баз данных в едино, в один общий xml файл.

Так вот следующие встреченные проблемы:

- unrar выдает комментарии 2 раза или не выдает их вообще. Отдельно читать комментарии архива я так и не научился (может кто знает как?). Писать отдельную утилиту для этого не хотелось бы, потому извращения с происходят с unrar
- Т.к. unrar выдает два раза комментарий в stdout приходится их по конвееру передать куда-то и выципить этот фрагмент комментария от туда в единственном эксземпляре.
- Сохранять на жесткий не подходит, да и в любом случае там столько мусора - что один фиг этот набор символов нельзя воспринимать как полноценный xml файл.
- После того, как этот фрагмент комментария будет выциплен, он будет добавлен в xml общий, где он нормально обработается и соберется сводная информация о базах данных.

**UPD2:**

На текущий момент реализовано в два прохода через sed - сначала получается список всех строк где встретились tag, затем через sed получаем данные с номера строки с первым tag под строку где оно встретилось второй раз. Чувствую, что можно все красивее реализовать, но не получается.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вы уже в курсе, что разбор XML регулярными выражениями — [гиблое дело](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/276994)?

Comment: думаю, человек готов к этому.

Comment: @pincher1519: Хм, а как вы извлекаете комментарии? Приведите командную строку, может, там что-то очевидное?

Comment: @VladD, строчка выглядит так:

    unrar l <имя архива>

Никакие ключи ни команды типа lt lb ничего не помагает. результат операции выглядит примерно так:

    <Комментарий>
    Comment: <Комментарий>
    Заголовок таблицы
    Список файлов и каталогов вместе с альтернативными потоками

Comment: @pincher1519: Хм, я посмотрел, и правда, это баг в unrar. Если есть возможность, попробуйте так:

    rar cw <имя архива>

Или даже так:

    rar cw <имя архива> -ierr 2>/dev/null

(или `2>nul`, если вы на Windows).

Comment: @VladD, Вообще, то что доктоктор прописал. Надо будет гендира раскошелить на rar. Пока триалка работает - полёт нормальный.

Comment: Тогда лучше всего, конечно, купить полный rar, тем более, он не дорогой. Удачи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если структура файла неизменна, попробуйте [так](http://pastebin.com/cZCK7C1i):

```
sed '0,/<tag1*/d; /<\/tag1/Q'
```

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, как это сделать sed'ом, но можно сделать awk.

```
cat x.xml | awk 'BEGIN {s=0;} /tag1/ { s = s + 1;next}  {if (s == 1) {print $0;}}'
```

s -  это счетчик tag1. если он равен 1 - выводим строку. Код конечно ненадежный, так как если в тексте встретиться tag1, то он будет работать неверно, но можно доделать

Теперь улучшенный вариант, который проверяет теги детальнее

```
cat x.xml | awk 'BEGIN {s=0;} /<tag1>/ { if (s!= 0) s = 1;next} /<\/tag1>/ {s = 2; next}  {if (s == 1) {print $0;}}'
```